# Large function gives me an error

Tags: excel

I have a column with 5 values and I want to get the three largest values.

I have a help coulmn eith 1-3.

[image]

```
=LARGE($H$5:$H$9, J5)
```

This gives me an error:
[image]

Comment: It's highlighting the range $H$5:$H$9 but not the cell J5 so there must be something wrong with the second part of the formula - maybe your Excel is set up to use a semicolon as a delimiter?

Comment: That does the trick. Thank you @TomSharpe!